# Clone object only with some params

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js

I want validate a Object and maybe this object can have extra params, but i only i want some. What is the best way to clone. I tried underscore, but nothing happens:

```
var object = {
      name: "Pepe",
      age: 25,
      widget: {
         top: 1,
         left: 1,
         other: "jeje"
      }
};
var a = _.pick(object, "name", "widget.top");
console.log(a);
//Will must return: {name: "pepe", widget: {top: 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = {
      name: "Pepe",
      age: 25,
      widget: {
         top: 1,
         left: 1,
         other: "jeje"
      }
};

var a = _.pick(object,'name','widget');
a.widget = _.pick(a.widget,'top');
```

Comment: Ok, so i need filter each nested objects as separate